# Can I create a functional interface that can store a method reference to methods containing any number of arguments?

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-interface

Suppose I have different methods on client objects that I need to keep references to as an argument to a higher order function on my end:

```java
// client class example methods
public Response method1(Request request);
public Response method2(Request request, String name);
public Response method3(Request request, String title, String description);

// my class
public Response invokeClientMethod(RequestHandler handler){
    // do something with method reference
}

// client code passes a reference to any of those methods as an argument to my function
myClass.invokeClientMethod(clientClass::method1);
myClass.invokeClientMethod(clientClass::method2);
myClass.invokeClientMethod(clientClass::method3);
```

These methods always take in a `Request` object as the first argument, return a `Response` object, and take an arbitary number of `String` arguments following the first `Request` argument. I want clients to be able to create any of those functions in the format above in their classes, then pass its method reference as an argument to my function.

Thus, I want to be able to keep references to all these methods using the same functional interface, if possible. I tried the following:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RequestHandler{
    Response apply(Request request, String... args);
}
```

But this functional interface can only keep references to methods that are explicitly vararg arguments themselves, like this:

```java
// client class
public Response method4(Request request, String... args);
```

By design, I do not wish for my clients to explicitly define their functions as vararg methods (`String...`) as it hurts readability. Can I create a functional interface that can store a method reference to methods containing any number of arguments **without being vararg functions themselves?**

I do not wish to end up doing something like this either:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RequestHandlerWithNoArgs{
    Response apply(Request request);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface RequestHandlerWithOneArg{
    Response apply(Request request, String arg1);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface RequestHandlerWithTwoArgs{
    Response apply(Request request, String arg1, String arg2);
}

// my class
public Response invokeClientMethod(RequestHandlerWithNoArgs requestHandler);
public Response invokeClientMethod(RequestHandlerWithOneArg requestHandler);
public Response invokeClientMethod(RequestHandlerWithTwoArgs requestHandler);
// ...
```

Comment: How would you actually plan on calling the method you get passed as `requestHandler`, what parameter would you pass in and how many? You will probably have to go with reflection instead of using functional interfaces. You will lose all type safety but that is because what you want to achieve cannot be done while being type safe imho.

Comment: not shown, but I actually have another parameter in the `invokeClientMethod` that I can deduce how many parameters that I need to pass to the `requestHandler`. My original plan was to just deduce that info and then call `.args` (partials) or `.apply` n times. I didn't want to use reflection exactly because I wanted to give my clients some form of compile-time safety – if i had my clients pass the fully qualified name of the method as a string instead, there'd be no way for me to verify if the method actually exists until runtime...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use method reference of a non-varargs method to implement a varargs method, because the compiler wouldn't know how to handle discrepancy between actual number of parameters passed at runtime vs. expected number of parameters required by the referenced method.

*You* have to do the mapping, e.g. using a simple lambda expression, ignoring discrepancies:

```
myClass.invokeClientMethod((r, a) -> client.method1(r));
myClass.invokeClientMethod((r, a) -> client.method2(r, a[0]));
myClass.invokeClientMethod((r, a) -> client.method3(r, a[0], a[1]));
```

That code ignores the fact that `a` may have the wrong length, i.e. any excessive values are ignored if the array is too large, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown if it is too short, and a `NullPointerException` will be thrown if the array is null (except in the first case).

If you want short arrays to simply pass null value, similar to how JavaScript function parameters are `undefined` when called with too few arguments, then *you* have to write the code for that in the lambda, e.g.

```
myClass.invokeClientMethod((r, a) -> client.method3(r, (a.length > 0 ? a[0] : null),
                                                       (a.length > 1 ? a[1] : null)));
```

The compiler cannot make that decision for you, which is why *you* have to do it, i.e. why a simple method reference is not enough.